# Helvetica Neue font defaults to medium instead of regular

Tags: fonts

I've installed the set of Helvetica Neue truetype fonts in my ~/.fonts directory, and they all show up correctly with `fc-list`. However, if an application selects the standard font, it's returning the medium style instead of the regular, e.g.:

```
$ fc-match "Helvetica Neue"
HelveticaNeueMedium.ttf: "Helvetica Neue" "中黑"
```

If I remove the medium font from the system, it gets the correct one:

```
$ fc-match "Helvetica Neue"
HelveticaNeue.ttf: "Helvetica Neue" "標準體"
```

I'm sure this can be corrected in `fonts.conf`, but what's the entry required? The only workaround I have right now is to remove the medium style as above, but this means I can't access it at all.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Using a copy of Hevetica Neue from a Mac, for testing purposes only, `fc-match "Helvetica Neue"` returns output as expected: `HelveticaNeue.ttf: "Helvetica Neue" "Regular"` – as such, this is likely a bug in the font files or the version of Ubuntu you were using at the time.